# Replace any character in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want convert this string:

```
string with characters like áéíóú
```

to

```
#################################
```

This `"parágrafo".replace(/\wW*/g, "#")` returns `"###á#####"`

Comment: @downvotes why?

Comment: So you want to convert all letters of string to #?

Comment: Yes @Eddie thats it

Comment: What's the purpose of `W*` in the regexp?

Comment: why not just `"parágrafo".replace(/./g,'#')` ??

Comment: Thanks @epascarello I not knows much about regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers using `.repeat()` are probably better ways to do this. This answer mainly serves to explain what's wrong with your code and how it could be done correctly.

`\w` doesn't match accented letters for some reason, that's why `á` ends up in the output. But even if this weren't a problem, it wouldn't match the spaces between words.

You can use `.`, which matches any character except newline.

```js
console.log("string with caracthers like áéíóú`".replace(/./g, "#"));
```

If you also want to replace newlines with `#`, add the `s` modifier.

```js
console.log(`string with caracthers like áéíóú
and also newlines`.replace(/./gs, "#"));
```

Oops, that's a very new feature in ES2018, not available in all browsers yet. You can use `/.|\n.g` for better portability.

```js
console.log(`string with caracthers like áéíóú
and also newlines`.replace(/.|\n/g, "#"));
```

Comment: In which browsers would that s modifier work atm? Firefox seems to fail on it.

Comment: Apparently that's a nonstandard extension. The standard JS flags are only `gimuy`

Comment: That's an extension of ECMA2018. It means it is part of the standard but not implemented yet by all major browsers.

Comment: So does that mean that Chrome already supports the look-behinds? I've read somewhere that it would be in the new ECMA. (don't have Chrome installed on this pc to test it)

Comment: @LukStorms Yes! `"abcde".match(/(?<=b)c/)` returns `"c"`

Comment: That's cool! Just a matter of time for the other browsers then.

Answer (score 2):

One option is using `repeat()`

```js
let str = 'string with caracthers like áéíóú';

let result = "#".repeat(str.length);

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Comment: To bad `repeat` isn't supported in Internet Explorer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
"#".repeat("string with characters".length)
```

No need for replace.

Answer (score 0):

`repeat()` cannot be used in IE so I will suggest looping over to the `str` length to get string with value `#`.

```js
let str = 'string with caracthers like áéíóú';
let result ='';
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
  result += '#';
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Barmar i didn't get you.

Comment: You still say to split the string and loop. You're not splitting any more.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your regex lost a few characters somewhere (and gained a `*`). It should be `/[\w\W]/` instead:

```js
var str = "parágrafo".replace(/[\w\W]/g, "#");

console.log(str);
```